# Как получить субтитры с Youtube java?

Tags: java, android

Как получить с Youtube api видео в приложение много информации нашел, а как можно в виде данных типа json и т.п получить субтитры из видео? чтобы можно потом с ними работать переводить сохранять и т.п.
хочу типа такого результат получить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]